# comparing Session-Value PHProblem

Tags: php, session, compare

```
if ($_SESSION['user_email']!=$_SESSION['ship_user_email'])
    {
        $to= $_SESSION['ship_user_email'];
        mail($to,$subject,$mail_html,$headers);
    }
```

there is problem in comparing values of both session. value is different but code not working.

Comment: Reminds me of a Dilbert: `Boss: Explain the problem to Tim in a way that he can understand. Dilbert: **THE SOFTWARE NO WORKY!!!**`

Comment: So you're saying the two `$_SESSION` values aren't equal, but the `mail()` command isn't getting run?

Comment: ya, mail()  command is not running...

Comment: Are you certain both $_SESSION array keys exists and session is successfully started ?

Does it show error(s) if you use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` before any other code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

print the values of both the session variables and check if there are leading or trailing spaces in the them.

Also check the condition with the '!==' as said by Kerry.
like this

```
if ( $_SESSION['user_email'] !== $_SESSION['ship_user_email'] )
    {
        $to= $_SESSION['ship_user_email'];
        mail($to,$subject,$mail_html,$headers);
    }
```

also check every step of your code by writing an echo statement and printing out the values of variables. This will help you debug and understand the code properly.

Comment: != operator used, !== it is not valid operator.

Comment: by echo both session vales two different mail id  print out, but not compared?

Comment: !== is a valid operator, check the manual. Go to this page for clarification http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

Try using the "!==" operator instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use <> this operator.